# Can my socket server routine work?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, client-server

I'm trying to build multiple client - one server structure. Each client makes connection to server and server maintains those connection.

Client have two thread(thread1, thread2) running asynchronously and sharing 1 socket to send, receive. Two thread each contain multiple send, receive function. For server to serve each client, it also have to make two client handler that share 1 socket.

I wanna have my server to create client handler routine(asynchronous task) only when their(each client) socket is ready-to-read to save resource. I'm trying to implement this feature using 'Socket.Select' method.

Here's my assumed implementation of server side select routine using code close to c#.

```
server.selectRoutine(){

while(!serverSocket.closed())
{
    checkReadList client_connect_socket_list_copy=new ArrayList<Socket>(client_connect_socket_list) ;
    Socket.Select(client_connect_socket_list_copy, null,null) ;

    foreach(Socket s in client_connect_socket_list_copy)
    {
        client_connect_info info=client_connect_info_dict.Items[s] ;

        if(!info.is_client_thread1_handler_active)
        {
            info.is_client_thread1_active=true ;
            clServerEntranceHandler handler=new clServerEntranceHandler() ;

            Task.Run(handler.run()) ;
        }

        if(!info.is_client_thread2_handler_active)
        {
            info.is_client_thread2_active=true ;

            clServerExitHandler handler=new clServerExitHandler() ;

            Task.Run(handler.run()) ;
        }           
}
```

Code Explanation

- Client_connect_socket_list: contains currently connected clients
- client_connect_info_dict: client connect info dictionary mapped for each socket as key.
- client_connect_info: consist of (is_client_thread1_Handler_Active, is_client_thread2_Handler_Active)
- Select only those sockets that are ready to be read after Socket.Select
- Run handler for those sockets where handler is currently not made, `info.is_client_thread1_Handler_Active=false`. And set `info.is_client_thread1_Handler_Active=true`. This is because there will be multiple `recv` function inside already-made handler and they are in blocking mode. So when client sends message to server destined to `recv` function blocked in already-made handler, Socket.Select will also think this socket as ready-to-read and it will end up creating new handler. To avoid this, i need to check whether handler is active. After handler finishes, it will set `info.is_client_thread1_Handler_Active= false` inside. Same for client_thread2 handler.

I think i now have to synchronize this routine with each handler already made. For example, avoid situation like `recv` function inside handler P snatch message A inside message queue of handler P's socket after Socket.Select saw message A inside message queue. Then handler P will end and set `info.is_Handler_Active=false`. Then `selectRoutine` will create new handler again for message A already read by handler P and there goes trouble.

I wanna know whether there is serious problem with this scheme that i should not use it. And if there is, then i wanna know better ways to implement multiple client - one server with room for scaling.

Comment: Just use WCF. Seriously. Sockets is very geek thing to use if you are not dealing with heavy load systems and low level protocols

Comment: Are you using one PC or multiple PCs?  If you are using one PC you have to use a different port number for each connection (client - server) while if multiple PCs are connecting to the same server you can use one port number.  You can have only one connection with the same 3 following items 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  So a Server usually listens to localhost (item 2 ). Each client has a IP and connects to sever with a port.  When you have multiple clients connecting to same server with same port number you have multiple connections with all 3 items the same and get an error

Comment: @jdweng i have multiple pc(raspberry pi) as clients and one Windows PC as server.Sorry i didnt mention that server manage array of  existing sockets, which is client_connect_socket_list_copy. Each clients will use their unique socket.

Comment: It should work provided the server only opens up one listener on the port number.  You should add to the array of sockets in the Async Accept method of the listener.  The listener defaults to accept up to 100 connections.  Every time a new client connect the Async Accept method gives a new socket 'ar' in the AcceptCallBack method.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example